# Print a form's image

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How to create and save a Image of my Windows Forms? it is possible?

Like This:

[image: Like This]

Comment: Did you want to capture the image of the form from VS in the designer or when the form is executing?

Comment: @ScottWylie module is executing on click event

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Bitmap` the same size as your form, and use the convenient [`Control.DrawToBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap.aspx) method. Here's a generic method that returns a `Bitmap`, which can be saved using - you guessed it - the `Save()` method:

```
public static Bitmap CaptureControl(Control c) {
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(c.Width, c.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24BppRgb);
    c.DrawToBitmap(b, b.ClientRectangle);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how to add this function on click event?

Comment: @jolly: Call it from your `Click` handler. If you don't know how to call a function, you need to revisit some C# basics.